# How to enable touchesMoved() with button action?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, touchesmoved

I am doing one piano application. There i am using button action to play music. But its not supporting drag functionalities. I have used touchesMoved(),touchBegan()  methods also . But nothigh is working.Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I am getting exactly what`s wrong is going with you why these methods are not get called ..can you explain me....?

Answer (score 2):

Button supports drag functionality. You should add your target by below control events.

```
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(action1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(action2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(action3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(action4) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```

Implement proper actions for each event and it should identify proper drag event.

Comment: can we add different control events for one button?

Comment: @deepti Yes you can, if you see the explanation of Apurv, he sets different actions for the same button.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.  Now I implemented that also. Its working fine.